# How can I change from nested dictionaries to a flat array?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to change this in python

Before :

```
{'NewYork': {'Paris': 12, 'Hawaii': 8, 'Tokyo': 11, 'Incheon': 12, 'LA': 2}, 
 'Beijing': {'Hongkong': 3, 'Cebu': 5},
 'Incheon': {'Cairo': 10, 'LA': 11, 'Tokyo': 1}, 
 'Tokyo': {'NewYork': 12, 'Paris': 14, 'LA': 9}}
```

After :

```
[("NewYork","Paris",12),
 ("NewYork","Hawaii",8),
 ("Newyork","Tokyo",11),
 ("NewYork","Incheon",12),
 ("NewYork","LA",2),
 ("Beijing","HongKong",3),
 ("Beijing","Cebu",5),
 ("Incheon","Cairo",10),
 ("Incheon","LA",11),
 ("Incheon","Tokyo",1),
 ("Tokyo","NewYork",12),
 ("Tokyo","Paris",14),
 ("Tokyo","LA",9)]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure about your final format? You want a _list_ or do you want want a _tuple_ with a list?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> before = {'NewYork': {'Paris': 12, 'Hawaii': 8, 'Tokyo': 11, 'Incheon': 12, 'LA': 2},
...          'Beijing': {'Hongkong': 3, 'Cebu': 5}, 'Incheon': {'Cairo': 10, 'LA': 11, 'Tokyo': 1},
...          'Tokyo': {'NewYork': 12, 'Paris': 14, 'LA': 9}}
>>>
>>> print [(key,k,v) for key,val in before.iteritems() for k,v in val.iteritems()]

[('NewYork', 'Paris', 12), ('NewYork', 'LA', 2), ('NewYork', 'Hawaii', 8), ('NewYork', 'Incheon', 12), ('NewYork', 'Tokyo', 11), ('Beijing', 'Hongkong', 3), ('Beijin
g', 'Cebu', 5), ('Incheon', 'Cairo', 10), ('Incheon', 'Tokyo', 1), ('Incheon', 'LA', 11), ('Tokyo', 'NewYork', 12), ('Tokyo', 'Paris', 14), ('Tokyo', 'LA', 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and two lots of iteration:

```
>>> city_pairings = {'NewYork': {'Paris': 12,
...                              'Hawaii': 8,
...                              'Tokyo': 11,
...                              'Incheon': 12,
...                              'LA': 2},
...                  'Beijing': {'Hongkong': 3,
...                              'Cebu': 5},
...                  'Incheon': {'Cairo': 10,
...                              'LA': 11,
...                              'Tokyo': 1},
...                  'Tokyo': {'NewYork': 12,
...                            'Paris': 14,
...                            'LA': 9}}

>>> flat = [(city, other_city, value)
...         for city, pairings in city_pairings.iteritems()
...         for other_city, value in pairings.iteritems()]

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(flat)
[('NewYork', 'Paris', 12),
 ('NewYork', 'LA', 2),
 ('NewYork', 'Hawaii', 8),
 ('NewYork', 'Incheon', 12),
 ('NewYork', 'Tokyo', 11),
 ('Beijing', 'Hongkong', 3),
 ('Beijing', 'Cebu', 5),
 ('Incheon', 'Cairo', 10),
 ('Incheon', 'Tokyo', 1),
 ('Incheon', 'LA', 11),
 ('Tokyo', 'NewYork', 12),
 ('Tokyo', 'Paris', 14),
 ('Tokyo', 'LA', 9)]
```

The second cities aren't exactly in the order you wanted as the dictionary sorts them according to some scheme. To have cities in the order they were inserted into the dictionary you'll have to do something else, using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), for example.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
 dict.items()
```